# How do I remove a site from squidGuard blacklist?

Tags: squid

I have just installed squidguard in my server to restrict porn or adult site. I followed [these instruction](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianEdu/HowTo/SquidGuard).

It's working great. Problem is squiguard list(blacklist) youtube.com as porn site. I want to remove youtube from blacklist. How can i do this?

Database save in `/var/lib/squidguard/blacklist/`...  I found several youtube site links in `blacklist/porn/uris` but when I tried to open it with gedit (with root permission) it says

```
some char does not show, modify this file can corrupt the file.`
```

Is there any good way to remove a site or add a site in squidGuard Blacklist?

Answer (score 1):

- Create a file `/var/lib/squidguard/blacklist/porn/urls.diff`
- Make the following entry in the file: -youtube.com
- Run the command:`squidGuard-u /var/lib/db/squidguard/blacklist/porn/urls.diff`

Answer (score 0):

you need to read this site betters and good , but this site will need you to monitoring much site as you will put or the porn site wont be blocked, but if you want to use just a string word like when i type porn from google it will blocked i think you need to know about regex for it using squid also work but it will block anything that related with the porn keyword here my recommended site to use the block website

http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-block-unwanted-website-in-ubuntu-linux/

and

http://www.wbitt.com/how-tos-tutorials/178-squidguard-addremove-websites.html

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/using-the-squidguard-blacklist-283096/

hope 3 of them help you bro.

Comment: unfortunately none of the link is useful :(. i checked each one. First one is not related with squidguard, 2nd one is backdated and 3rd one did not help. thanks for you reply